# An example of matrices such that "AB=E, but not of BA"

Tags: matrices

One of my classmates ask me a question, but I could not find an anti-example: I want to find an example of matrices such that "AB=E, but not of BA"

where, A and B are matrices (both square and not are ok) on the complex field and E is the identity matrix.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please try phrasing the question differently ?

Comment: Is $E$ an identity matrix or any matrix?.  Are $A$ and $B$ square matrices?

Comment: Thanks so much for remind me of the condition, my English is pool and this is my first time to ask a question here, so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot happen with square matrices. If $AB=\operatorname{Id}$, then both $A$ and $B$ are invertible, and $B=A^{-1}$. But then $BA = A^{-1}A = \operatorname{Id}$.

On the other hand consider $A = \left(1 \quad 0 \right)$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.  Then $AB = (1)$ and $BA = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.